# Creating Firefox profile with responsive design preset

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to mobile automation. How can I create Firefox profile with responsive design preset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`devtools.responsiveUI.presets`](https://github.com/DjangoFR/firefox.devtools.responsiveUI.presets) firefox preference.

Example, using Python:

```
import json

from selenium import webdriver


presets = [
    {
        "key": "480x800",
        "name": "Google Nexus one",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 800
    },

    # TO FILL

    {
        "key": "1680x1050",
        "name": "Desktop - stat 2.96%",
        "width": 1680,
        "height": 1050
    }
]

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('devtools.responsiveUI.presets', json.dumps(presets))

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Also, see:

- [Responsive Design View Presets in Firefox for Web Development](https://sridharkatakam.com/responsive-design-view-presets-firefox-web-development/)