# Responsive design view on Firefox with Webdriver

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium Webdriver on Ruby, is there a way to set up Firefox to be opened on "[Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View)" and continue executing tests for the whole session?

I've done it on Google Chrome and it's working fine (sans the touch support part). For Firefox, I've only seen questions around [creating preset for screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641779/creating-firefox-profile-with-responsive-design-preset) but not much activity on how to actually execute tests on said profile.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using Capybara with selenium?

Comment: Nope. We use vanilla selenium although we put a lot of custom methods on top of it to suit our functionality.